# How to get DAG info from MS Exchange Server 2010 using LDAP Query from AD?

Tags: active-directory, exchange-server, exchange-server-2010, ldap-query

I wanted to know about LDAP Queries used to get more information about Exchange Server.
What I am interested in knowing more about Data Availability Groups, Statistics Regarding them and Replication Status etc.
I know there are some CmdLets but I want to avoid using PowerShell.

I want to know any possible way of getting same info from Active Directory for Exchange Server.

Comment: If you don't want powershell then it might be best to remove the tag for it ;)

Comment: Can you give more details on the informations you want to retreive ? And perhaps give the CmdLets you don't want to use.

Comment: @JBlanc, I know cmdlets like Get-DataAvalabililtyGroup, Get-DataAvailabilityGroupNetwork etc. But for some reason I want to fetch same info from AD usding LDAP. 
Do you have any idea how can I do that?

Comment: Thanks Bali, Removed PowerShell Tag and added one for AD :-)

Answer (score 0):

That's a cool idea!

It's all there in the configuration partition under:

> CN=Microsoft Exchange,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=xx,DC=xx.

The C# code below will retrieve the server roles, and should help get you started.

The Role info comes from [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb123496%28EXCHG.80%29.aspx).

```
        using (DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://RootDSE"))
        {
            var NamingContext = de.Properties["configurationNamingContext"][0];
            using (DirectoryEntry de_NC = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + NamingContext))
            {
                using (DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(de_NC))
                {
                    ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");

                    ds.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=msExchExchangeServer)(msExchCurrentServerRoles:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))";
                    Output("Mailbox Role Servers:", ds, "cn");

                    ds.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=msExchExchangeServer)(msExchCurrentServerRoles:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=4))";
                    Output("CAS Role Servers:", ds, "cn");

                    ds.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=msExchExchangeServer)(msExchCurrentServerRoles:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=16))";
                    Output("Unified Messaging Role Servers:", ds, "cn");

                    ds.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=msExchExchangeServer)(msExchCurrentServerRoles:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=32))";
                    Output("Hub Transport Role Servers:", ds, "cn");

                    ds.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=msExchExchangeServer)(msExchCurrentServerRoles:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=64))";
                    Output("Edge Transport Role Servers:", ds, "cn");
                }
            }
        }


    static void Output(string Titel, DirectorySearcher ds, string Property)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Titel);
        SearchResultCollection src = ds.FindAll();
        foreach (SearchResult RoleServer in src)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(RoleServer.Properties[Property][0].ToString());
        }
        if (src.Count < 1)
            Console.WriteLine("---");

        Console.WriteLine();
    }
```

Comment: (DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://RootDSE")                                          This line will give info of the current domain. What if I need to find the same info of a different domain?(I have the username and password for the other domain). Any help is appreciated.